# Useful form of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\trace{trace}$Let $A \in \SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\trace(A)>2$. The assumptions on the determinant and trace are equivalent to having eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $1/ \alpha$. $A$ can be written $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D=diag(\alpha, 1/ \alpha)$. Is it true that $$
A=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & b \\ 0 & 1/\lambda \end{pmatrix} .
$$

Comment: It is true for Jordan normal form of $A.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. Alternatively take any general linear $P$ and multiply the RHS.